# Redux react webpack's hot module reload actions show warning, webpack stuck at errors

Tags: webpack, redux

I want to use webpack HMR to reload redux reducers and auto reload when modifying or adding new actions; However it show the warning, when after I edit action files.

> [HMR] unexpected require(811) from disposed module 76

And when these have errors in action file Webpack HMR stuck at the following logs, how can I config webpack to ignore these errors?

> [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
>
> [WDS] App hot update...

Code I've used:

```
if(module.hot){
    module.hot.accept(); // accepts any JS file change.
    module.hot.addStatusHandler(function(status){
        if(status === "idle"){
            const {appStore} = require('./appStore');
            store.replaceReducer(appStore); // reload reducers
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you try `require('./appStore').default` instead of `require('./appStore')`? I had to do something like this when migrating from Babel 5 to 6.

Comment: @bebraw yesterday: require('./appStore') work well with Babel 6 :)

Comment: It's working now? If so, set up an answer and accept that. :)

Comment: @bebraw: I mean it is not because of babel version. The problem relates to Webpack HMR config(or its code), but I've not fixed it :(.

Comment: Ok. That `default` trick fixed it for me. It's hard to say anything concrete without having a runnable example.